# Why was this question on cross-nation collaboration closed?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/whats-the-best-researchers-could-do-for-their-native-country) on what's the best researchers could do for their native country was closed. It reads like a sentimental question and may even lead to chatty answers, but doesn't it have some potential? I cut off the emotional and patriotic part and this question seems to ask for thoughts on how to transcend country-borders in academic collaboration. With a minor edit, shouldn't that be on-topic?

Another grouse is with the answer: 1) it is fitting as a comment. 2) it does not answer the question. 3) it reads like a rant. Somehow the irrelevant answer has got 5 votes.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with the the closing. The question is not really related to Academia; it's asking about how academics can be patriotic. That's a nice goal, but being patriotic doesn't have anything to do with being in academia.

Additionally, the question is very broad; what's "the best" someone can do is hardly an answerable question. The best they can do towards what end? Improving academics? Improving science awareness? Helping out research causes?

The question may be salvageable, but I agree with the closing as-is.

Comment: Hmmm, yes. If it's about patriotism, then it's best junked. But the last sentence (some ideas like volunteering for seminars, extending hands for collaborations, encouraging new institutes of education) looks seeking general ideas for collaboration and hence my question.

Comment: @Bravo - Even the last few sentences are still very broad, containing a few arbitrary examples of possible volunteer opportunities.

Answer (score -2):

I voted to close this question because it does not seem a real question. It is more like advocating an idea. And as I emphasized in my answer, it approaches the idea from a wrong direction.

I think I should defend my answer too. The main point of my answer is: in order to attract any collaboration in any academic activity, the responsible organizations "must" 1. provide strong incentives, 2. maintain a productive and (less bureaucratic) academic atmosphere. Then, academic collaboration will happens naturally.

Comment: "it approaches the idea from a wrong direction" = that is wrong from your perspective. One cannot apply close votes because of difference of perspective. I agree with @eykanal that it is broad.

Comment: I agree with @Bravo. If you think the question is a bad question, you can downvote, but you should only cast votes to close for the specific reasons stated in the closing dialog.

Comment: @eykanal: My main reason for voting to close the question was it does not seem a real question, which is one of the reasons mentioned in the closing dialog.

Comment: That's fine, but your answering the question suggests that you thought it *was* a real question, as you were able to answer it. I guess the main point here is, try to stay consistent.

Comment: A part of the question was advocating this idea that experts in abroad should find a way to promote science and technology in their native country. My answer refers to this part of the question by emphasizing the importance of incentives.